# understanding the landau small o in trigonometric taylor expansions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

i am having an hard time understanding how the small o power works, because from wolfram i see something, in some sites something else and from my teacher even another way and i really don't get what's the right one and why it is the right one, i am just going to give some examples,

from wolfram alpha: sin x= x-$\frac{x^3}{3!}+$ $\frac{x^5}{5!}$ +o(x$^7$) (here it looks like the small o has the successive odd term, but if i press the "show more terms" button it becomes: sin x= x-$\frac{x^3}{3!}+$ $\frac{x^5}{5!}$-.....$\frac{x^{21}}{21!}$ +o(x$^{22}$) (i didn't write down the whole terms because it isn't important from what i am asking) in here the small o's degree is just the succesive even one, so what's supposed to be the right pattern? something else i have seen is in another site is: sin x= x-$\frac{x^3}{3!}+$ $\frac{x^5}{5!}$ +o(x$^5$) which makes things even more confusing, so what's supposed to be the right way of putting small o's "degree"

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)

Comment: does wolfram uses small or big o?

Comment: basically if use small o you just use n degree and if you use big O it is n+1?